# XPath query in DB2

Tags: xml, xpath, db2

I'm performing the following query in DB2 on a XML column and it works fine:

```
SELECT  
FROM customer
WHERE contains(search_text, 
'
@xpath:''/customer/number[. contains("123456")]''
', 'RESULTLIMIT = 100')=1;
```

but the following query doesn't work:

```
SELECT  
FROM customer
WHERE contains(search_text, 
'
@xpath:''/customer/number[. = "123456"]''
', 'RESULTLIMIT = 100')=1;
```

Any ideas why the second query doesn't work?
The error I get is:
ERROR [38H10] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL20423N  Error occurred during text search processing on server "localhost" using index "CISC_CUSTOMER". The error message is ""IQQS0032E The query cannot be processe".

```
<customer>
<number>
123456
</number>
<firstname>
John 
</firstname>
<lastname>
Smith
</lastname>
</customer>
```

Comment: please give the xml sample..

Comment: what your `search text` contains..

Comment: The xml code that I added is what the SEARCH_TEXT column contains. Is that what you mean Babai?

Comment: I think `' @xpath:''/customer/number[. contains("123456")]'' '` is wrong.. correct ?

Comment: Indeed, I don't understand how XPath expression `/customer/number[. contains("123456")]` can work, it should be something like `/customer/number[contains(., "123456")]`, no?. As for the second XPath expression, I think you should remove leading and trailing whitespace and do `/customer/number[normalize-space(.)="123456"]`. **NOTE:** I do not know how DB2 processes XPath expressions

Comment: @pault. I have the same feelings... OP probably swap his/her confusion.. :)

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/12/db2-native-xml/ and
, http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/sqlxml-vs-xquery/ might help you

Answer (score 0):

In DB2 you can only use "=" on attributes, on elements I can only use "contains".